# Transformation of acyl group to carboxyl group in biphenyl system with two acyl groups at para position

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How do I perform this reaction?

I have prepared 4,4'-acylbiphenyl and want to make one acyl group into $\ce{-OH}$ and other into $\ce{-COOH}$ group.

Answer (score 5):

Is it correct that you are aiming to synthesize 4-(4-hydroxyphenyl)benzoic acid [58574-03-1]?

[image: 4-(4-hydroxyphenyl)benzoic acid]

The target compound is available in one step from biphenyl using potassium peroxydisulfate $(\ce{K2S2O8})$ as an oxidant, Palladium(II)-trifluoroacetate, $\ce{Pd(OCOCF3)2}$, as a catalyst, and formic acid as the carbon source for the $\ce{-COOH}$ group. The synthesis was published in
 *Org. Lett.*, **2004**, *6*, 2437-2439 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ol049166l)).

---

**EDIT**

Limited resources and experience will probably rule out *Stille*-type coupling reactions too.

Alternatives pretty much depend on which 4,4'-disubstituted biphenyl are available.

A methoxyarene can be converted to the corresponding phenol by $\ce{BBr3}$
or the cheaper hydrobromic acid. The $\ce{-OCH3}$ group resists oxidation, is a **+M** substituent and is not acidic. All this might be helpful (see below).

In order to introduce the $\ce{-COOH}$ substituent, two approaches seem to be possible in an undergrade lab:

- oxidation of a methyl group by permanganate
- *Grignard* reaction of a bromoarene with carbon dioxide

[image: retrosynthesis]

Comment: Thank you sir. But I am just a UG student and I don't think these reagents will be available for me sadly.